# how to pass variable parameter to zsh command line?

Tags: zsh, aws-sam

I have the following bash command

```
sam deploy -g --guided --profile test-name --region us-west-2
```

there is a repetative part of this command that is `--profile test-name --region us-west-2`

I want a way to write bash command where i could add that to a variable so i dont have to type with every new command.

e.g `same deploy -g --guided custom_var_name`

below is what i have tried

seems like i have the answer by declaring a variable in bash and re-using the variable.

1. `vim ~/.zshrc`
2. declare a variable you would like to re-use, for me it was

   `aws='--profile test-name --region eu-west-2'`
3. restart the terminal and use the command the following way.

   sam deploy -g --guided $aws

above doesnt work

Comment: What have you searched for and tried so far?  Edit your question and include a code block with what you have attempted and any errors you have encountered.

Comment: @j_b. i have updated the question.

I think what i added as an answer didnt work

Comment: Try double quoting the "$aws" variable in your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array

```
aws=(--profile test-name --region eu-west-2)

sam deploy -g --guided $aws
```

or wrap the entire command in a function

```
aws_deploy () {
    sam deploy --profile test-name --region eu-west-2 "$@"
}
```

that's you'll call like

```
aws_deploy -g --guided custom_var_name
```

Comment: For completeness: I think this is one of the rare cases, where an alias would be easier (less work to set up) than a function.

Comment: Good point. The only thing that might trip that up is (and I'm not familiar with `sam`, so this might be an easily resolved issue) it's not clear from the question if `--guided` takes an argument or not. (And if I think about it hard enough, either solution here could suffer from whatever problem I imagine the alias would.)

Comment: using array solves my problem, what i was seeking is basically not wanting to type the param flags again and again for every command really.

Comment: guided is not must be, i will leave that out of argument. I am curious to know what problems we will have with alias as you suggested @chepner

Comment: "Problem" may have been a overstatement. It would be *awkward* for an alias like `alias aws_deploy='sam deploy --guided'` to split the option/argument pair like this, so that the argument to `--guided` would suddenly appear to be a positional "argument" for the alias.